# Show that $ L(E_\lambda(M))\subseteq E_\lambda(M) $ for all $\lambda\in F$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was given this following question in my linear algebra module:

Let V be a vector space over a field F and let L, M be two linear transformations from V to itself.
Suppose $L\circ M= M \circ L $. Show that $ L(E_\lambda(M))\subseteq E_\lambda(M)  $ for all $\lambda\in F$.
(Where $E_\lambda(M)$ is the eigenspace of M)

I'm not really sure where to start as I'm having trouble in understanding how we can apply L to $E_\lambda(M)$ as it implies that we're applying a linear transformation to a subspace not a vector from V.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is standard notation:
$$L(E_{\lambda}(M))=\{L(v)|\ v\in E_{\lambda}(M)\}.$$
So show that if $M(v)=\lambda v$ then $M(L(v))=\lambda L(v)$.

Comment: @Servaes thanks a lot for that I had not seen that notation before!

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $ f : A \rightarrow B $ and $ E \subset A $ then $ f(E) $ denotes the image of $ E $ by $ f $, that is the set of the images of the elements of $E$.

Now on to the real question. You want to prove that if $ MX = \lambda X$, then $ MLX = \lambda LX$, which would show the inclusion. Commutativity of $ M $ and $ L $ would surely help here, right?

Remember, if you're stuck on problems like these, with lots of notations and concepts, just break them down step by step with their definitions until you reach something simple enough (not too simple though) to really grasp what's being asked, until you  get familiar enough with them.